# One-Time Use Randomized Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Tables (columns) that are important here (there are more in my actual DB but I simplified):

- Patients(PatientID, PatientNumber, DOB, Weight, RandomCode)
- RandomNumbers(RandomNumberID, Available)
- Sites(SiteID, SiteNumber)

Patients does not contain any data and is to be populated via a 3rd party GUI. RandomNumbers contains 50 entries. When a patient's data is first added to Patients, a random number 1-50 is selected, which is tied to RandomNumberID. The "available" column in RandomNumbers is treated as a boolean (T meaning available, F meaning unavailable). After the RandomNumberID is tied to a patient, that RandomNumberID cannot be used again (Available is switched to "F"). If an already used RandomNumber is assigned to a patient upon data entry, another randomly selected RandomNumberID is selected until one is found where Available is T.

Here is the stored procedure that I've written so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspPatientEntry
    @intPatientID      AS INTEGER OUTPUT,
    @intPatientNumber  AS INTEGER,
    @intSiteID         AS INTEGER,
    @intRandomCode     AS INTEGER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT    ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT @intPatientID = MAX (intPatientID) + 1
    FROM TPatients TP (TABLOCKX)

    SELECT @intPatientID = COALESCE(@intPatientID, 1)

    SELECT @intPatientNumber = CONCAT(@intSiteID, @intPatientID)

    INSERT INTO TPatients (intPatientID, intPatientNumber, intSiteID, intRandomCodeID)
    VALUES (@intPatientID, @intPatientNumber, @intSiteID, @intRandomCode)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

And here is another function I wrote to test it out:

```
DECLARE @intPatientID AS INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE @intSiteNumber AS INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE @intPatientNumber AS INTEGER = CONCAT(@intSiteNumber, @intPatientID);
DECLARE @intRandomCode AS INTEGER = FLOOR(RAND()*50)+1; -- This just picks a random integer 1-40. <- this is the heart of my question

EXECUTE uspPatientEntry @intPatientID OUTPUT, @intPatientNumber, 2, @intRandomCode
```

Would something like this work? Ignore syntax, just the general idea:

```
DECLARE @intRandomCode AS INTEGER;

SELECT @intRandomCode = FLOOR(RAND() * 50 + 1; 
FROM TRandomCodes TRC
WHERE TRC.blnAvailable = "T"

UPDATE TRandomCodes TRC
SET TRC.blnAvailable = "F"
WHERE @intRandomCode = TRC.intRandomNumberID;
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't see why not, although it is a somewhat strange setup to want. You may want `UPDLOCK` hint on the `SELECT @intRandomCode` part to prevent race conditions. `@intPatientID` should be an `IDENTITY` column instead of messing around with `SELECT MAX + 1`, and `@intPatientNumber` obviously cannot be a concat if it is itself an integer, for this you probably want a computed column anyway. `

Comment: Its not clear exactly are you asking? Did it work when you tried it? You can test it easier than we can?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want to attach random data to patient records. If you're thinking of using this for some kind of patient security requirement, such as 2FA, please consider other options. Have a read through [RFC6238 TOTP: Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238) and other papers on Two-Factor Authentication.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm currently in school and it's simply part of the assignment requirements.